# How to create an Accumulo Range object using the Ruby Thrift client

Tags: python, ruby, thrift, accumulo

I have Accumulo 1.5 running with the Thrift Proxy.  I'm connecting to thrift with Ruby, but I imagine the same situation would arise if I were working with Python.

I have been able to connect to Accumulo, create updates, and scan the table by specific columns.  I'm trying to query by a specific Row ID.

```
querykey = Key.new('row'=>rowid)
querykey_end = Key.new('row'=>"#{rowid}\0")
queryrange = Range.new('start' => querykey, 'startInclusive' => true, 'stop' => querykey_end, 'stopInclusive' => false)
queryscanoptions = ScanOptions.new({'range' => queryrange})
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error on my Range constructor.

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3) (ArgumentError)
```

There isn't exactly much (any) documentation on the Ruby client, so I've been working mostly off of the thrift code.  The Range class is defined in `proxy_types.rb`, but it is defined the same way as the other Thrift classes I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a namespace issue.  The Accumulo Thrift code all exists in the root namespace, but Ruby has it's own `Range` class that was not getting overridden.  This problem exists up to Accumulo 1.5.0.  To solve it, I went over to github, and grabbed the generated Thrift code from the 1.5.2 branch where all of the Thrift objects are placed in an Accumulo namespace.  Now I can call `Accumulo::Range.new` and it works like a charm.  The update also added a namespace to the Python thrift code.

Accumulo 1.5.2 Ruby Thrift code is here: https://github.com/apache/accumulo/tree/1.5.2-SNAPSHOT/proxy/src/main/ruby

This is the commit that fixes everything: https://github.com/apache/accumulo/commit/27ee2367056e5ad0cb6175f91154cd13d49e2c95

Comment: You should use the recently released 1.5.1.

Comment: Awesome!  It looks like 1.5.1 came out today.  The 'latest' version on Apache's website was still 1.5.0 when I posted this yesterday.

Comment: Yep, I finalized everything today ;)